# Converting XSD Schemas to Classes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am working on a project that consumes (external) services.

The vendor has provided a whole heap of XSDs (89 of them) and I want the convert them all into .Net (C#) classes / class library.

I am using the XSD utility on these but as there is a lot of cross-referencing and importing, they are failing with error messages saying `type 'xxxxx' not declared`

Now, based my my googling, this is quite simply overcome by compiling the complete reference "tree" but ....

1. I have 89 files to convert
2. It concatenates all the schema names together for the output .cs file name (and breaks due to being too long (> 260char))

I thought about creating a class library assembly, starting with the base level schemas (ones without imports) and then telling XSD to convert a schema but use any referenced types from this assembly... but I am not sure how or even if it is possible.

So, how can I best do this please... any advice is welcome..

And yes, 89 schemas are a lot and unfortunately, I have no control on this, I just have to suck it up and deal with it.

Comment: I really need to see a sample of xml where code is failing.  Usually when a 'type' is used in xml serialization it indicates there is an inherited class.  Usually to test xml serialization I create a set of test class with data then serialized the data to a file.  Then reverse the process and de-serialize  the data.  You can then compare the serialize xml file with your actually xml supplied from vendor.

Comment: Not XML ... XSD.... Question title may be causing ambiguity to has been changed

Comment: Do you have `.asmx` or `.wsdl` link to the service? If yes, then try generate classes by adding `Service Reference...` in VS Solution Explorer.

Comment: XSD is the schema for XML.  The actual input files will be XML.  I think the vendor expects you to change 'xxxxx' in file to real value.

Comment: @jdweng - I am trying to create a class library from XSDs ... Not from XML

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Yes I do have the WSDL .. but the problem is there are multiple services and they use common types but importing the service then creates duplicate types in different namespaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/P[arameters]:file.xml` [option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_1) in xsd.exe to specify many parameters in separate file instead of pass them in command line.

Sample of this xml:

```
<xsd xmlns='http://microsoft.com/dotnet/tools/xsd/'>
    <generateClasses language='CS' namespace='MyNamespace'>
        <schema>FirstSchema.xsd</schema>
        <schema>SecondSchema.xsd</schema>
        <schema>ThirdSchema.xsd</schema>
    </generateClasses>
</xsd>
```